# can we add a number directly in datetime variable in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a variable @var1 date time

Will the below query work
Set @var1 = @var1 +1

I want to increment date by 1 in @var1

Will the above method or 
Dateadd(dd,1,@var1) be more efficent

Comment: Definitely use `DATEADD()`, always. Forget about performance, but the lazy `+1` syntax is not only not intuitive to the next person who reads the code, it also won't work with the new data types (`date`, `datetime2`, etc).

Comment: [Also see this blog post](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Even if it syntactically valid, it is not immediately obvious to the next person who reads your code what is actually happening).

In some platforms, date-and-time values are radixed on the day, so `x + 1` is the next calendar day, and a fractional day is that number of seconds or minutes.

Other platforms store or represent date-and-time values as integer seconds (or miliseconds, or even nanoseconds) since some epoch value, in which case `x + 1` adds 1 second or whatever the base unit is to the value.

For best results (consistent on every platform, and to be immediately obvious) use the platform's built-in date library. In SQL that is the `DATEADD` function, where you specify the quantity you want to add to the date.

Your question asks if `+ 1` or `DATEADD` is "more efficient". I'll say you don't use SQL to be "efficient" - there are inherent inefficiencies in SQL and database systems; it can be said developer productivity and bug-avoidance is far more important, in which case you should use `DATEADD`.